# Error when trying to create a variable that stores a range of characters: TypeError : indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and have been tasked to prompt the user to enter a string, and from there generate a random number that will be a valid index of the user's string, and whatever the generated index is till the end of the string I have to replace the characters within that range with "*".

e.g. (desired output) 
Please enter a string: hello 
*assume random index is 2* 
The new string is: he***

What I was thinking of doing is firstly creating a variable that stores the range of characters that I am trying to replace, like so:

```
user_string = "sentence xyz"
length_of_string = len(user_string)
index_start = random.randint(1,length_of_string)
chars_to_replace = user_string[index_start:]
```

This worked well and printing out the chars_to_replace variable to test worked as expected. 
I then wanted to create another variable that stores the rest of the characters that were to remain, like so:

```
chars_to_keep = user_string[:chars_to_replace]
```

This line of code resulted in this error message:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

What I was ultimately trying to do was to replace all the characters in the chars_to_replace variable with * and concatenate it with the other chars_to_keep variable and as a result produce a similar result to the desired output above.

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong that would be greatly appreciated, additionally our teacher wanted us to showcase our understanding of what she has taught us, (really basic string manipulation) so solutions that employ complex line(s) of code is probably out of scope for this simple task. I know y'all probably find it absurd that I'm essentially asking for a super inefficient way of solving this task when there's a simple way of doing it but this will help me understand the basics better and build a good foundation to work with, thanks!

Comment: Maybe you meant this? `chars_to_keep = user_string[:index_start]`

Comment: Oh wow, not sure how I didn't think of that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in:
`chars_to_keep = user_string[:chars_to_replace]`
is that you are trying to slice using a string instead of an Integer.
***chars_to_replace*** is a string and not an Integer.

Correct code would be:

```
chars_to_keep = user_string[:index_start]
```

Also your overall code could look like this for the expected output:

```
user_string = "sentence xyz"
length_of_string = len(user_string)
index_start = random.randint(1,length_of_string)
result = user_string[:index_start] + '*' * (length_of_string - index_start)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to `chars_to_replace` is not an integer. For slicing, it should be an integer. To achieve your goal it can be achieve like this

```
user_string = "sentence xyz"
length_of_string = len(user_string)
index_start = random.randint(1,length_of_string)
chars_to_keep = user_string[:index_start] + '*' * (length_of_string - index_start + 1)
print(chars_to_keep)
```